# Annotate stacked Histogram in ggplot with percentages or shares

Tags: r, ggplot2

Man, I can't figure this out...

**I got this**

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
    ggplot(aes(mpg, fill = factor(am))) +
    geom_histogram(position = "fill", bins = 7)
```

[image]

**I want this**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge there is no easy out-of-the-box way to label a histogram with percentages. Instead you have to do the computations manually. To this end I added a helper function `pct_bin` which computes the share of each group per bin using the values `..x..`, `..count..` and `..group..` returned by `stat_bin`. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

pct_bin <- function(group, x, count) {
  count_bin <- tapply(count, x, sum)
  
  count / rep(count_bin, length(unique(group)))
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, fill = factor(am))) +
  geom_histogram(position = "fill", bins = 7) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(..group.. == 2, round(pct_bin(..group.., ..x.., ..count..), 2), ""),
                vjust = ifelse(round(pct_bin(..group.., ..x.., ..count..), 2) < 1, -.5, 1.5)), 
            position = "fill", stat = "bin",  bins = 7)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer. Unfortunately, I was really looking for a `ggplot` answer. :( But still a good solution.